# Simple card game

Tags: javascript, loops

I've created a simple higher or lower card guessing game, it works but once it completes once it then loops through the game logic n^2 times and I cant explain why. I'm really new to coding and JavaScript and I cant figure out what's happening. The issue I currently have is while I'm able to look up concepts in isolation I don't understand enough about the bigger picture to know what interaction is causing the looping.

less useful further info:
Currently the whole script is really a proof of concept, ultimately I will replace the deck building function and just use the random number generator to find images of cards, record all of the previous game events and remove cards from the deck as the game progresses but I cant have it looping by the square of the number of times its been through the game cycle.

Here is the code, please feel free to talk to me like I'm 5, I currently feel like a monkey with a gun.

```
console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> SCRIPT START");
console.log("variables are defined");
var suitClubs = [];
var suitDiamonds = [];
var suitHearts = [];
var suitSpade = [];
var history = [];
var userGuess;
var activeCard;
var nextCard;

var randomSuitOne;
var randomCardOne;
var randomSuitTwo;
var randomCardTwo;

var activeCardValue;
var nextCardValue;

var gameCycle = 0;

const card = document.querySelector(".card");
const title = document.querySelector(".title");
const historyP = document.querySelector(".history-p");

console.log("buildDeck() is called")
buildDeck();


function buildDeck() {
    console.log("Deck is built");
    for (i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
        suitDiamonds.push(i + " Diamond");
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
        suitHearts.push(i + " Heart");
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
        suitClubs.push(i + " Club");
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
        suitSpade.push(i + " Spade");
    }
    var deck = suitClubs.concat(suitDiamonds, suitHearts, suitSpade);
    console.log("cardChoice is called");
    cardChoice();
};

function cardChoice() {
    gameCycle = gameCycle + 1;
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GAME CYCLE START");
    title.innerHTML = "Higher or Lower!"

    activeSequenceCard();
    // console.log("activeSequenceCard is called to randomize the active card");

    function activeSequenceCard() {
        randomSuitOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        randomCardOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 13));

        switch (randomSuitOne) {
            case 1:
                activeCard = suitClubs[randomCardOne];
                break;

            case 2:
                activeCard = suitDiamonds[randomCardOne];
                break;

            case 3:
                activeCard = suitSpade[randomCardOne];
                break;

            case 4:
                activeCard = suitHearts[randomCardOne];
                break;
        }
        card.innerHTML = activeCard;

        nextSequenceCard();
        // console.group("nextSequenceCard is called to randomize the next card in the deck")
    }

    function nextSequenceCard() {
        randomSuitTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        randomCardTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 13));

        switch (randomSuitTwo) {
            case 1:
                nextCard = suitClubs[randomCardTwo];
                break;

            case 2:
                nextCard = suitDiamonds[randomCardTwo];
                break;

            case 3:
                nextCard = suitSpade[randomCardTwo];
                break;

            case 4:
                nextCard = suitHearts[randomCardTwo];
                break;
        }
        historyP.innerHTML = ("The next card will be: " + nextCard);
        console.log("randomSuitOne is: " + randomSuitOne + " randomCardOne is: " + randomCardOne);
        console.log("randomSuitTwo is: " + randomSuitTwo + " randomCardTwo is: " + randomCardTwo);
        gamePlay();
    }
}

function gamePlay() {

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("game-button")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

            userGuess = parseInt(this.value);

            console.log("The users guess was button (" + this.value + ") " + this.innerHTML + " and is a: " + typeof this.value);

            switch (userGuess) {
                case 1: console.log("User clicked HIGHER");
                    if (activeCardValue <= nextCardValue) {
                        console.log("Case 1: TRUE fired");
                        title.innerHTML = "CORRECT!"
                        setTimeout(cardChoice, 2000);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Case 1: FALSE fired");
                        title.innerHTML = "GAME OVER!"
                    }
                    break;

                case 2: console.log("User clicked LOWER");
                    if (activeCardValue >= nextCardValue) {
                        console.log("Case 2: TRUE fired");
                        title.innerHTML = "CORRECT!"
                        setTimeout(cardChoice, 2000);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Case 2: FALSE fired");
                        title.innerHTML = "GAME OVER!"
                    }
                    break;
            } console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GAME CYCLE ENDS, this is cycle: " + gameCycle);
        })
    }

    activeCardValue = activeCard.split(" ");
    activeCardValue = parseInt(activeCardValue.splice(0, 1));
    console.log("activeCardValue is: " + activeCardValue);

    nextCardValue = nextCard.split(" ");
    nextCardValue = parseInt(nextCardValue.splice(0, 1));
    console.log("nextCardValue is: " + nextCardValue);

}
```

Comment: You should not call `addEventListener` repeatedly on the same button (which you do through recursive calls), as that will make a click execute the same callback multiple times. BTW, you asked a question before, which got answers, but you never reacted to them with either a comment or an acceptance mark...

Comment: As mentioned above, you should either call "addEventListener" only once or remove the event listener before calling "cardChoice" again.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah the previous question from 2015? I've just flagged that because I didn't ask it (!) I've only recently started learning JS. Ill try moving the for loop so its not getting called every time !!